# Azure - How to list all the Databricks Workspaces in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Could someone please let me know how to list all the DBR workspaces under a particualr subscription in Azure.

I have tried Az Cli Option but it doesn't have any option to list any workspace.

Answer (score 2):

you can always use something like this:

```
az resource list --resource-type "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
```

so use a generic command to query the rest api directly (what the other answer suggests) but using Azure CLI, so you dont need to handle the auth\tokens\etc

ps. you'd first need to change your Azure CLI context to that subscription with:

```
az account set -s "sub_name_goes_here"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/listbysubscription),

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01
```

Comment: which one? i guess i posted before you!

Comment: you posted only the rest api path, not the azure cli. whereas after that you copypasted azure cli bits. thats easily traceable with edit history

Comment: oh dude! if you feel so, i will remove that part 